# basic authentication on apache

Tags: java, apache

I have a java web application which is using Apache as the front end to Tomcat. 
I have basic authentication configuration in web.xml file

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>
    </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint> 
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Now I want to setup this configuration on apache

I have created users file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2\conf directory and added username/password.

I add this line in httpd.conf file

```
<Location "/secure/*"> 
    AuthUserFile conf/users
    AuthName "This is a protected area" 
    AuthType Basic 
    Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

When I open application with browser http://example.com/app/secure it dose not prompts for authentication. What dose wrong here ?

Comment: (a) Did you create the user file using the apache passwd utility? (b) Did you restart apache or signal it to reload its configuration? (c) Do you have any virtual servers running in this apache?

Comment: Yes I use passwd utility, then restart apache. I don't have virtual servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive should be:

```
<Location "/app/secure/">
```

Without the `*`. The `Location` directive automatically applies to that URL and everything under it (`/app/secure/myServlet`, `/app/secure/more/otherServlet` etc).

If you want pattern-matching in the location, you should use `LocationMatch`, but I think for your case it's unneccessary.

Note that the `Location` string has to be the whole path starting from the slash after the domain. So if your domain is `http://example.com/app/secure/`, the `Location` is not just `/secure/` but rather `/app/secure/`.

Alternatively, if you are actually accessing your application with `app/secure` rather than `app/secure/`, you should remove the last slash:

```
<Location "/app/secure">
```

`/app/secure/` matches `/app/secure/something`, but it doesn't match `/app/secure`. `/app/secure` matches  `/app/secure/something` but also `/app/secure` itself.

Comment: Oops. Now I saw your last sentence in the question, I noticed that it really should be `/app/secure/`. Updating my answer.